# Enable a COM Addin programmatically

Tags: c#

Sometimes when running my add-in using excel it gets disabled. Is there a way I can programmatically enable it?

I have tried something like this but `COMAddin` doesn't have a name property.

Here's what I have so far.

```
 xl.Application myApp;
 myApp = (xl.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

 foreach (COMAddIns currentAddIn in myApp.COMAddIns)
 {
     if(currentAddIn.Name=="Create")
     {  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
foreach (COMAddIn currentAddIn in myApp.COMAddIns)
{
     if (currentAddIn.ProgId == "Create" && !currentAddIn.Connect)
     {
        currentAddIn .Connect = true;
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. However I need to close out and re-open excel to see the addin again. Do you know if there is a way of seeing the enabled adding without closing and re-opening excel